# Hashing function for external file Java

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to create a hashing function in order to place nodes onto a RandomAccessFile.

The size of my node is 256 bytes.I read somewhere that the length should be double the size of the total nodes. I will be placing 1,000 nodes onto the file so I chose 2,000 as the total size.

I tried using this formula

int position = key.hashCode() & (2000 - 1)

But I keep getting positions that are too small to  hold the nodes. For example when I print the positions I get

Position 521 and 524

But my node is 256 bytes so if I was to write one node at position 521 and another at 524 they would overlap... right?

I've tried a range of hashing functions from stackoverflow and other resources on the internet but I can't find one that works.

Comment: When you mention the length, to which length do you refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 1000 nodes, then 521 and 524 represent positions in multiples of 256. The actual position in bytes is computed by multiplying this number by 256, or by shifting it left by 8.

**Note:** The truncation trick that uses `& (x-1)` works only when `x` is a power of 2. Since 2000 is not a power of 2, you cannot use `& (2000 - 1)` to truncate your hash code.

You have two options here:

- Use `%` instead, i.e. `key.hashCode() % 2000` (pay attention to negative numbers), or
- Use the next power of 2, i.e. 2048: `key.hashCode() & (2048 - 1)`

Comment: I've tried using key.hashCode() & (2048 - 1) but I get positions 524 and 537... I guess I'm not really understanding how it's being stored onto the file. So you're saying if I write to the file the node in position 524 and another node in 537 they should both fit fine with no overlap?

Comment: @Mango The first sentence talks about this: you need to multiply the position that you get by the size of your node, i.e. use file positions 524*256 and 537*256.